# How split routes using react-router-config and webpack2

Tags: reactjs, react-router, webpack-2

I try use two variants config:

```
export const routes = [
{component: App,
    childRoutes:[
        {
            path: isDev + '/',
            exact: true,
            component: App,
            name: 'Главная',
            show_in_menu: true,
            sys_name: 'main',
        },
        { path: isDev + '/task/list',
            exact: true,
            name: 'Задачи',
            show_in_menu: true,
            sys_name: 'tasks',
            getComponent: (location, cb) => {
                System.import('./containers/Task/list')
                    .then(function(m) {
                        console.log(m);
                        cb(null, m)
                    })
                    .catch(errorLoading);
            }
        },
        /*...*/
    ]
}];
```

or

```
export const routes = [
{ path: isDev + '/',
    exact: true,
    component: App,
    name: 'Главная',
    show_in_menu: true,
    sys_name: 'main',
},
{ path: isDev + '/task/list',
    exact: true,
    name: 'Задачи',
    show_in_menu: true,
    sys_name: 'tasks',
    getComponent: (location, cb) => {
        System.import('./containers/Task/list')
            .then(function(m) {
                console.log(m);
                cb(null, m)
            })
            .catch(errorLoading);
    }
},
        /*...*/
    ]
}];
```

But in fist variant always mounting App component, in second i have error:

`Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of`Route`.`

If i delete `exact: true` always rendering App component and never TaskList.

How setup code spliting with react-router-config and webpack2?

Comment: System.import is deprecated. maybe thats why youre getting that error. try logging your System.import if it does return the component

Comment: No. Trouble in version router - 4. Function `getComponent` not working. Instead need async component, example https://gist.github.com/acdlite/a68433004f9d6b4cbc83b5cc3990c194

Comment: you dont have to use react router 4 if you wnt the getcomponent to work. downgrade it. downgrade all your libraries and follow the versions compatible for  the example that you are using